# What is this syntax called? And where is it explained in the Scala documentation?

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

Going through a [tutorial](http://danielasfregola.com/2015/02/23/how-to-build-a-rest-api-with-spray/) on Spray, I encountered this:

```
entity(as[Quiz]) { quiz => requestContext =>
        val responder = createResponder(requestContext)
        createQuiz(quiz) match {
        case true => responder ! QuizCreated
        case _ => responder ! QuizAlreadyExists
    }
}
```

This specific line is where the confusion lies:

```
entity(as[Quiz]) { quiz => requestContext =>
```

What in the world is with the second `=>` sign???
What does this syntax mean and where can I find the documentation for further reading??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I put the parenthesis like this, does it make more sense?

```
entity(as[Quiz]) { quiz => (requestContext =>
      ...  
      )
    }
}
```

This is just a curried function with two arguments, and mechanically it is a function that returns another function. Example:

```
val test: Int => Int => Int = a => b => a + b // the same as a => (b => a + b)
println(test(2)(3))  //5
```

You can think of it as `(a, b) => a + b`, but with the added benefit so you can partially apply it easier:

```
val t: Int => Int = test(2)
println(t(3)) // 5
```

Comment: Could you link the documentation? I'm ready to accept this as the correct answer

Comment: I'm really not sure it is explained exactly in this syntax, but it should be obvious if you read about normal (not anonymous) curried functions: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/currying.html and then just apply lambda syntax to this principle: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html

Comment: Other way to ensure that is to write a curried named function from the first link: `def modN(n: Int)(m: Int) = ((x % n) == 0)` in REPL, and then print it's type: `:t modN _`. This will result in `Int => (Int => Boolean)`